# SQL - LAG to get previous value if condition using multiple previous columns satisfied

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I have a table created by:

```
CREATE TABLE #test_table 
(
id INT
,EventName VARCHAR(50)
,HomeTeam VARCHAR(25)
,Metric INT
)

INSERT INTO #test_table VALUES
(1, 'Team A vs Team B', 'Team A', 5),
(2, 'Team A vs Team B', 'Team A', 7),
(3, 'Team C vs Team D', 'Team C', 6),
(4, 'Team Z vs Team A', 'Team Z', 8),
(5, 'Team A vs Team B', 'Team A', 9),
(6, 'Team C vs Team D', 'Team C', 3),
(7, 'Team C vs Team D', 'Team C', 1),
(8, 'Team E vs Team F', 'Team E', 2)
```

Which results in:

```
id  EventName           HomeTeam    Metric
------------------------------------------
1   Team A vs Team B    Team A      5
2   Team A vs Team B    Team A      7
3   Team C vs Team D    Team C      6
4   Team Z vs Team A    Team Z      8
5   Team A vs Team B    Team A      9
6   Team C vs Team D    Team C      3
7   Team C vs Team D    Team C      1
8   Team E vs Team F    Team E      2
```

A want to calculate a new column `PreviousMetricN` where N can be 1, 2, 3, ... which shows the previous value for `Metric`, but only if the `HomeTeam` was involved in the previous event. For example:

```
id  EventName           HomeTeam    Metric  PreviousMetric1 PreviousMetric2
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   Team A vs Team B    Team A      5       NULL            NULL
2   Team A vs Team B    Team A      7       5               NULL
3   Team C vs Team D    Team C      6       NULL            NULL
4   Team Z vs Team A    Team Z      8       NULL            NULL
5   Team A vs Team B    Team A      9       8               7
6   Team C vs Team D    Team C      3       6               NULL
7   Team C vs Team D    Team C      1       3               6
8   Team E vs Team F    Team E      2       NULL            NULL
```

I have been trying variations of `LAG` with a new grouping variable in the `PARTITION BY` clause such as

```
LAG(Metric) OVER(Partition by (CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(HomeTeam, EventName)>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ORDER BY id)
```

but without any success. How can this be done?

EDIT:
I've also asked this question for Pandas here:
[Pandas shift - get previous value if multiple conditions satisfied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66858486/pandas-shift-get-previous-value-if-multiple-conditions-satisfied)

Comment: why PreviousMetric1 for id=5 should not be 7? and what is PreviousMetric2?

Comment: please explain what you are looking for in  simple words.

Comment: Please check my answer. It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see no answer here that uses window functions and a single scan of the table. We can do this query **in a single scan** as follows:

Let us assume you have the `AwayTeam` in another column.

> **If you don't have this yet and you wanted to parse it out of `EventData`:**
> We could use: `SUBSTRING(EventData, CHARINDEX(' vs ', EventData) + 4)`
> **I urge you** to follow proper normalization and create this as a proper column in your table.

Our algorithm runs like this:

1. Multiply out (unpivot) the two teams as separate rows, using `CROSS APPLY`
2. Calculate the previous `Metric`s using `LAG`, partitioning by the merged `Team` column
3. Filter back down the doubled up rows, so that we only get a single row for each of our original ones

```sql
SELECT id, HomeTeam, AwayTeam, Metric, Prev1, Prev2, Prev3
FROM (

  SELECT *
    ,Prev1 = LAG(Metric, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY v.Team ORDER BY id)
    ,Prev2 = LAG(Metric, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY v.Team ORDER BY id)
    ,Prev3 = LAG(Metric, 3) OVER (PARTITION BY v.Team ORDER BY id)
    -- more of these ......
  FROM test_table
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES (HomeTeam, 1),(AwayTeam, 0)) AS v(Team,IsHome)
) AS t

WHERE IsHome = 1
-- ORDER BY id  --if necessary
```

Importantly, we can do this without the use of multiple different sorts, partitions or ordering, and without the use of a self-join. Just a single scan.

Result:

| id | HomeTeam | AwayTeam | Metric | Prev1 | Prev2 | Prev3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Team A | Team B | 5 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
| 2 | Team A | Team B | 7 | 5 | (null) | (null) |
| 3 | Team C | Team D | 6 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
| 4 | Team Z | Team A | 8 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
| 5 | Team A | Team B | 9 | 8 | 7 | 5 |
| 6 | Team C | Team D | 3 | 6 | (null) | (null) |
| 7 | Team C | Team D | 1 | 3 | 6 | (null) |
| 8 | Team E | Team F | 2 | (null) | (null) | (null) |

Comment: It's a wise approach and definitely the most efficient solution among all. Best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

The logic seems to be:

```
lag(metric, <n>) over (partition by hometeam order by id)
```

I don't see why `eventName` is needed.

Comment: Ah - I should have explained more clearly. Because the `HomeTeam` can be involved in a game but not be the `HomeTeam` in that game. Question is updated now to demonstrate this

Answer (score 1):

Using `OUTER APPLY` and correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT *
FROM test_table c
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 PreviousMetric1 = c2.Metric  
             FROM test_table c2 
             WHERE CHARINDEX(c.HomeTeam, c2.EventName)>0 
               AND c.id > c2.id
             ORDER BY id DESC) s1
OUTER APPLY (SELECT PreviousMetric2 = c2.Metric  
             FROM test_table c2 
             WHERE CHARINDEX(c.HomeTeam, c2.EventName)>0 
               AND c.id > c2.id
             ORDER BY id DESC OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY) s2            
ORDER BY id;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=02fc7fa9489bb4e5c1a45a9aa6183760)**

Output:

```
+-----+-------------------+-----------+---------+------------------+-----------------+
| id  |    EventName      | HomeTeam  | Metric  | PreviousMetric1  | PreviousMetric2 |
+-----+-------------------+-----------+---------+------------------+-----------------+
|  1  | Team A vs Team B  | Team A    |      5  |                  |                 |
|  2  | Team A vs Team B  | Team A    |      7  |               5  |                 |
|  3  | Team C vs Team D  | Team C    |      6  |                  |                 |
|  4  | Team Z vs Team A  | Team Z    |      8  |                  |                 |
|  5  | Team A vs Team B  | Team A    |      9  |               8  |               7 |
|  6  | Team C vs Team D  | Team C    |      3  |               6  |                 |
|  7  | Team C vs Team D  | Team C    |      1  |               3  |               6 |
|  8  | Team E vs Team F  | Team E    |      2  |                  |                 |
+-----+-------------------+-----------+---------+------------------+-----------------+
```

Extedning with `PreviousMetricN` is a matter of adding corresponding `OUTER APPLY` sN with `OFFSET N-1 ROWS FETCH ...`.

Answer (score 1):

First through self join and common table expression I have ranked all the previous eventname containing hometeam. We can have PreviousMetric1 from previous match and we can use Lead() window function to obtain PreviousMetric2. Please check below query:

```
with cte as(
select a.id,a.eventname,a.hometeam,a.metric,b.metric PreviousMetric1,   
LEAD(b.metric)over (partition by a.id order by b.id desc) PreviousMetric2,
row_number()over(partition by a.id,a.hometeam order by b.id desc) rownum
from #test_table a
    left join #test_table b
        on charindex(a.hometeam,b.eventname)>0  and a.id>b.id
)select id,eventname,hometeam,metric,PreviousMetric1,PreviousMetric2  from cte 
where rownum=1
```

[image]

You can also have PreviousMetric3 applying Lead() with 2 as second parameter. In this way you can have any number of previous metric. It's faster comparing to any other approach.

```
;with cte as(
    select a.id,a.eventname,a.hometeam,a.metric,b.metric PreviousMetric1,   
    LEAD(b.metric)over (partition by a.id order by b.id desc) PreviousMetric2,
    LEAD(b.metric,2)over (partition by a.id order by b.id desc) PreviousMetric3,
    row_number()over(partition by a.id,a.hometeam order by b.id desc) rownum
    from #test_table a
        left join #test_table b
            on charindex(a.hometeam,b.eventname)>0  and a.id>b.id
    )select id,eventname,hometeam,metric,PreviousMetric1,PreviousMetric2 ,PreviousMetric3 from cte 
where rownum=1
```

[image]

Comment: A nice solution, but I'm going to have to award @Charlieface's solution because of its efficiency and only one scan through the table, avoiding self joins, multiple sorts, etc.

Comment: It's satisfying to know that, you got your desired solution. And yes if you consider another  column as Away team then it's better solution. Best wishes. It was a nice challenge to work on. Your question deserves a up vote.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
;with cte as (
   select id
 , eventname
 , hometeam
 , metric
 , CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(HomeTeam, EventName)>0 THEN LAG(Metric) OVER (Partition by HomeTeam ORDER BY id) ELSE NULL END previous from  #test_table 
)
select * ,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(HomeTeam, EventName)>0 THEN LAG(previous) OVER (Partition by HomeTeam ORDER BY id) ELSE NULL END previous2 
from cte
order by 1
```