# preserving first or last row when using shift to conditionally slice a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 0, 1, 0, 1], 'b':[0, 0, 0, 1 ,0]})
```

I want to select rows is the `df` that the value in `a` is greater than the value in `b` in previus row so I used `shift(1)`:

```
df_shift = df.loc[df.a > df.b.shift(1)]
```

This gives me row `2` but I want to always preserve the first row since there is no value to compare before row `0`.

This is the result that I want:

```
   a  b
0  1  0
2  1  0
```

I have read these two posts: [post_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36042804/how-to-shift-a-column-in-pandas-dataframe-without-losing-value), [post_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66858486/pandas-shift-get-previous-value-if-multiple-conditions-satisfied). And I have tried the following code which gives me the result that I want but obviously it has been achieved by using `concat`.

```
df_concat = pd.concat([df.iloc[[0]], df_shift], 0)
```

Is there another way to do it?

Comment: added a solution. does it work for you?

Comment: @Naveed it works for this sample. Let me check it with my original dataframe and I will inform you within a couple hours. For now a big thumbs up for your ty :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way to do it, just check that the when previous b value is null, it gets selected

```
df.loc[(df.a > df.b.shift(1)) | df.b.shift(1).isnull()]
```

```
    a   b
0   1   0
2   1   0
```